# UIView removeFromSuperview removes also subs from subview?

Tags: ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to know if a removeFromSuperview does remove also subviews from the subview (in case if i have more image-views in a scrollView as Subview....).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view has at most one superview. The view you call that method on will break exactly this one link. If that view has subviews they will disappear but keep connected to that very view.

Comment: Thank you.
So for memory issues i should run through the subviews of the subview and remove them before i remove the "main subview" ?